# How do the review queues work?

Tags: support, reviewing

I've been in the [Review page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review) recently. I was just wondering how the review queues for the different categories work.

If I reviewed a 'first post', ' late answer' or a 'low quality' post, will that same post still be shown to other users with enough rep to review? If yes, how many other users will see a post I've already reviewed  and what factors decide the amount of users reviewing the same post?

I'm asking because there are 'first posts' or 'low quality' posts about games I'm unfamiliar with, but with spelling, grammar or formatting that I can improve. It would be better, IMO, if other users familiar with the game posted about also see those posts in their review queues after I've already edited them. This is to check if there are issues with the content of the post. Otherwise, I'd just not edit them (click 'Not sure') to make it appear on another user's review queue.